# No compiler can produce code for this Qt version - Apple silicon

Tags: c++, qt, apple-silicon

I am trying to port a linux project to macOS. However I can't even setup the build environment on an M1 Macbook Air 2020 (Apple silicon). I installed qt-creator, cmake, qt 5.15 and 6.1 using homebrew. I added the qt versions and cmake in the qt-creator settings. When I want to put everything together in the kits tab, I get the error in the title.

Checking the compilers tab, I realized that the autodetected clang compilers are x86 only. So I cloned the x86 clang++ entry and changed the ABI from x64 to arm. This should work I though, since `clang++` is a unversial binary as `file /usr/bin/clang++` reports

```
/usr/bin/clang++: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e]
/usr/bin/clang++ (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/clang++ (for architecture arm64e): Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e
```

What do I have to do to make Qt Creator able to build universal binaries? Or at least any build at all?

Comment: My team has ported Qt 5.15 to M1 and done considerable amount of work to cross compile our project for universal builds.  But I don't think I understand your question.  Can you make it more clear?

Comment: Note that the architectures clang's executable *contains* (as a fat binary) and the architectures of binaries that clang *can generate* (as a compiler) are two different things and not necessarily related to each other.

Comment: I know @JeremyFriesner. However I am not able to build anything at all at the moment

Comment: @selbie I changed the question slightly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [Qt 6.2](https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-6.2-lts-released) version which brings support for `macOS on Apple Silicon`. Porting tasks were tracked under this [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-85279). Currently, Qt5 doesn't support building for M1 chip.

In addition to updating to `Qt6.2` you also need to update your `Qt Creator` version to Qt Creator **6**. Alternatively, you can try the build flags below with Qt Creator 5.

As *Qt Creator 5* is built as a non-universal binary, it will *default to producing x86_64 binaries*, regardless of which architecture your machine is. To build for *arm64*, add  **-DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=arm64** explicitly to the "Initial CMake parameters" of the project build settings, or **QMAKE_APPLE_DEVICE_ARCHS=arm64** to the qmake "Additional arguments" field.